# Запятая и тире или только тире?

Tags: пунктуация

*Ты не святой(,) – постановочной

стала, медийная Русь.*

Это две стихотворные строчки.

Comment: В предложение надо забить кол осиновый. Или объясните, что за выверт авторский, что он вообще хотел сказать?!

Comment: Автор хотел сказать, что Россия стала не святой, а постановочной. Это стихотворная строчка.

Comment: А Матвей Дёмин что хотел? Почему «в предложение»? Можно ещё хоть строку из этого стиха?

Comment: Вернее, это две стихотворные строчки. Мне интересно, то, что я спросил: знаки препинания после слова "святой".

Comment: В предложении, конечно. Опечатка.

Comment: Это похоже на игру: карты раздали, а какая игра — не сказали.

Comment: Понимаете какая штука, если автору угодно называть это (...нужное вписать) стихотворением, а язык, на коем это (...) написано, -  русским, то уж со знаками он как-нибудь сам разберется.

Comment: Здесь нарушены элементарные логические связи: обращение сделано к некой "медийной Руси", которая якобы должна была "стать" святой, а стала "постановочной" (заказной или ещё какой-то), в то время как "святой" в таких сетованиях обычно относят к прошлому, да и здесь желаемый смысл наверняка был в том, что "Русь перестала быть святой, а стала медийной + постановочной", но это невозможно отнести к "медийной Руси", поскольку к таковой обращаются.

Comment: @Alex_ander, +много. Тут хуже даже. Пока Екатерина не разжевала, я даже грамматику не понял. Получалясь, что "Медийная Русь" кому-то говорит, что "он не святой". К черту такие стихи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ты не святой, – (а) постановочной

стала, медийная Русь. (это обращение)

Будем молиться и праздновать,

клясть ненасытность жулья...

Скоро заточкой с алмазами

станет Россия моя.

ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС

Да, в предложении можно поставить запятую и тире на месте пропущенного союза А. Обычно в этом случае ставится только тире, но здесь одного тире может быть недостаточно, так как структура предложения  сложна для понимания и может быть иначе истолкована. Поэтому в качестве авторского знака постановка запятой и тире вполне возможна.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ

Полный текст приведен для лучшего понимания смысла первых двух строк.

Comment: Вы читать не пробовали вопрос?

Comment: Благодарю, Sibylla.

Comment: И всё-таки запятая лишняя.

Answer (score 5):

***Ты не святой – постановочной стала, медийная Русь.***

Нужно только тире. Оно выражает противопоставление и ставится вместо запятой и союза А.

**Союзы при однородных членах предложения (противительные) иногда опускаются. Когда один из них пропущен, между ними пишется тире. Пример: не малый рыбачий парус - корабли снятся мне.** [Союзы и знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения](http://fb.ru/article/203602/soyuzyi-i-znaki-prepinaniya-pri-odnorodnyih-chlenah-predlojeniya-pravilo)

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина.